# Using Nightwatch, how do you get the DOM element, and it's attributes from the ELEMENT entity?

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

I've noticed some strange behavior where elements that are present in the view are not being located by nightwatch. In order to see exactly what is visible, I'd like to iterate through the view that nightwatch has opened, and get a list of every element that it can locate, and get the relevant information from that result about what those elements are. I've been able to 'find' all the elements with the following:

```
 browser.elements('css selector', 'div', function (elements) {
   elements.value.forEach(function(element){
     console.log('result', element)
   })
 })
```

The catch is that the result is a series of these: `{ ELEMENT: '0.9107972990792419-3' }`

How do I get the `class`, and all the other relevant information about the element from the nightwatch `ELEMENT`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will want to use `.elementIdAttribute` for this.

```
browser.elements('css selector', 'div', function(elements) {
  elements.value.forEach(function(element){
    browser.elementIdAttribute(element.ELEMENT, 'class', function(attribute) {
      console.log(attribute.value);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: element.ELEMENT gives 'undefined'.

Comment: Maybe now it does. This was valid back in 2017 when I posted the answer.

Comment: okay! do you know any way to do it now?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't been using nightwatch in several years. I'm not up to date on any new changes.